# Regex: match all phone number except one

Tags: regex

I'd like to create a Regex that matchs all phone numbers except one.
So, for instance, if I have a text:

> "Hey, my phone number is 0498995859 but you can call me also: 0466655522"

I want to catch `0498995859` but not `0466655522`.

+ I'd like to match also when it's written like this: `sddkkd0498995859fsdkfd`

I tried several things but with no success :(

Comment: Please post your solution or what you have tried so far, so we can assist in the resolution of your problem

Comment: "I tried several things but with no success :("  --> what did you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one does the job:

```
(?<!\d)(?!0466655522)\d{10}(?!\d)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!\d)         : negative lookbehind, make sure we don't have a digit before
(?!0466655522)  : negative lookahead, make sure we don't have the number "0466655522"
\d{10}          : 10 digit
(?!\d)          : negative lookahead, make sure we don't have a digit after
```